# Hyper-V server 2008 connecting to LAN Router?

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v, disk-image

Looking at setting up Hyper-V server 2008 on new Dell T610 and migrating DC + 2 other VMs on there. I would try before asking but don't have the server as yet, couple of questions spring to mind if I may:

1 - Can you boot clients via iso? With VMWare I could set-up an iso as CD ROM, is this possible with Hyper-V server 2008?

2 - Can I change the physical NIC settings on  Hyper-V set-up to match those of my router / Hardware firewall allowing access to internet for host? I need host and all guests to match the current subnet 192.168.45.0 / 255.255.255.0. This would also allow me to store images on network drives.

3 - My DC will be a guest using static IP as it is now on the domain, are all workstations able to still see as usual, I'm guessing it will broadcast as normal?

4 - Does Hyper-V server 2008 have drive space that I can store images/backups on, is that accessible for domain admins, if I need to drop files locally for example?

Kind regards

Gary

Answer (score 1):

Gary:

1. Yes, Hyper-V Virtual Machines can either access the Host cdrom drive or alternatively you can mount an ISO file.
2. Yes, when you install Hyper-V you will be asked to choose a physical network adapter to be used as the virtual adapter for the VM's. When you create new VM's you assign this virtual network adapter to them. When you install Windows inside the VM you then configure its networking settings - and match them up with your network scope. The VM will then be able to communicate with everything on your network
3. Yes the DC will work perfectly normally. I would recommend you still keeping 1 physical domain controller and use it as the time server for the other domain controllers. I took over a network admin role where they didn't have a physical DC and they had ALL SORTS of horrible domain/active directory problems. For your own sake - have a physical domain controller.
4. Not 100% sure - I have not used Hyper-V Server 2008 R2. I would think not as the ONLY role that you can do with Hyper-V Server is Hyper-V hosting - not file sharing. I would think that you would have to keep the ISO's on a file server and when you are managing the Hyper-V Server 2008 R2 from the Hyper-V administrator console you would attach the ISO's from the file server.

Matt

Comment: Hi Matt & thanks for the advice.

3 - Hmm that could be an issue, moving to a small office where I will only have room for 1 tower server which will be the hyper-V, I currently have 3 rack servers. I wont be able to have a physical DC so may need to research that before diving in.

4 - When I have set-up the Hyper-V server 2008 minus any guest VMs do you know how would I point it to a file server to collect the iso and machine images needed for windows installs?

Thanks again.

Comment: No problems:

3. Even just an old system with 512mb of RAM would do for the physical domain controller. It's best practice to have more than 1 DC in any case. Definitely something you should look into.

4. What you would do is download the "Hyper-V Administration Console" for your desktop operating system. This would allow you to remotely manage the Hyper-V role on the Hyper-V 2008 Server. From here you would be able to create new VM's and attach ISO images either from your local computer, or a network drive (your file server).

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes, you can boot from an ISO

[> You can use either physical media or an image file (.iso file).](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732470%28WS.10%29.aspx)

2) Yes, you can create an external virtual network (see the bottom of the page under [additional considerations](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732470%28WS.10%29.aspx))

3) Yes, the virtual machine will behave as if it were a physical machine on the network.  The physical machine will actually be using a virtual nic after you set up the external virtual network.

4) I would just use a normal share for this.  Hyper-V doesn't allow the type of Drag-And-Drop file sharing that VMWare or Virtual-PC.